# fetch call from javascript unable to reach java REST service

Tags: javascript, json, rest, post, fetch

I'm learning REST API and trying to call a POST service, written in java, from Javascript using fetch. Request is not reaching the service when the @Produces and @Consumes are MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON

I have also defined other simple POST and GET methods in the same API which are working fine but the case when I have to send and receive JSON data is not working.

Below is my fetch call:

```
    let options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: new Headers({'content-type': 'application/json'}),
    body: JSON.stringify({
          "Title": "title"
          })
    };
    const url = "http://localhost:8080/myserver/data/list";
    return fetch(url, options);
```

Below is my REST API:

```
 @Path("/data")
 public class Controller {
 @POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/list")
public Response createList(CreateListJsonData dta) throws IOException {
System.out.println("in create list");
return Response.status(200)
            .entity("{\"dummykey\"}:\"dummyVal\"")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT")
            .build();
}
```

CreateListJsonData  class is as below:

```
 @XmlRootElement
 public class CreateListJsonData {
    private String Title;
    public String getTitle() {
        return Title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        Title = title;
    }
 }
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>myserver</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.myserver</param-value>
    </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I'm running the API on tomcat on eclipse. when I trigger the request I get below messages on console:

```
 com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.AbstractWadlGeneratorGrammarGenerator attachTypes
 INFO: Couldn't find grammar element for class javax.ws.rs.core.Response
```

Can anybody please help me to figure out my mistake here?

Comment: `INFO:` - that's not an error, so presumably a response is sent to the client

Comment: as you are setting a `content-type` that's not considered "standard" in CORS, you are triggering a `CORS preflight` OPTIONS request - does your server handle `OPTIONS` request method? `.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT")` suggests not

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a cross-domain situation, [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests).

With this content-type, the request is no longer "simple", but is a [Preflighted request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests). It requires that your server handles the OPTIONS method (in addition to the POST which you handle). See the linked article for headers that it needs to return. Typically, something like this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-PINGOTHER, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```